# Using numpy.take for faster fancy indexing

Tags: python, numpy

**EDIT** I have kept the more complicated problem I am facing below, but my problems with `np.take` can be summarized better as follows. Say you have an array `img` of shape `(planes, rows)`, and another array `lut` of shape `(planes, 256)`, and you want to use them to create a new array `out` of shape `(planes, rows)`, where `out[p,j] = lut[p, img[p, j]]`. This can be achieved with fancy indexing as follows:

```
In [4]: %timeit lut[np.arange(planes).reshape(-1, 1), img]
1000 loops, best of 3: 471 us per loop
```

But if, instead of fancy indexing, you use take and a python loop over the `planes` things can be sped up tremendously:

```
In [6]: %timeit for _ in (lut[j].take(img[j]) for j in xrange(planes)) : pass
10000 loops, best of 3: 59 us per loop
```

Can `lut` and `img` be in someway rearranged, so as to have the whole operation happen without python loops, but using `numpy.take` (or an alternative method) instead of conventional fancy indexing to keep the speed advantage?

---

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**
I have a set of look-up tables (LUTs) that I want to use on an image. The array holding the LUTs is of shape `(planes, 256, n)`, and the image has shape `(planes, rows, cols)`. Both are of `dtype = 'uint8'`, matching the `256` axis of the LUT. The idea is to run the `p`-th plane of the image through each of the `n` LUTs from the `p`-th plane of the LUT.

If my `lut` and `img` are the following:

```
planes, rows, cols, n = 3, 4000, 4000, 4
lut = np.random.randint(-2**31, 2**31 - 1,
                        size=(planes * 256 * n // 4,)).view('uint8')
lut = lut.reshape(planes, 256, n)
img = np.random.randint(-2**31, 2**31 - 1,
                    size=(planes * rows * cols // 4,)).view('uint8')
img = img.reshape(planes, rows, cols)
```

I can achieve what I am after using fancy indexing like this

```
out = lut[np.arange(planes).reshape(-1, 1, 1), img]
```

which gives me an array of shape `(planes, rows, cols, n)` , where `out[i, :, :, j]` holds the `i`-th plane of `img` run through the `j`-th LUT of the `i`-th plane of the LUT...

All is good, except for this:

```
In [2]: %timeit lut[np.arange(planes).reshape(-1, 1, 1), img]
1 loops, best of 3: 5.65 s per loop
```

which is completely unacceptable, especially since I have all of the following not so nice looking alternatives using `np.take` than run much faster:

1. A single LUT on a single plane runs about x70 faster:

   ```
   In [2]: %timeit np.take(lut[0, :, 0], img[0])
   10 loops, best of 3: 78.5 ms per loop
   ```
2. A python loop running through all the desired combinations finishes almost x6 faster:

   ```
   In [2]: %timeit for _ in (np.take(lut[j, :, k], img[j]) for j in xrange(planes) for k in xrange(n)) : pass
   1 loops, best of 3: 947 ms per loop
   ```
3. Even running all combinations of planes in the LUT and image and then discarding the `planes**2 - planes` unwanted ones is faster than fancy indexing:

   ```
   In [2]: %timeit np.take(lut, img, axis=1)[np.arange(planes), np.arange(planes)]
   1 loops, best of 3: 3.79 s per loop
   ```
4. And the fastest combination I have been able to come up with has a python loop iterating over the planes and finishes x13 faster:

   ```
   In [2]: %timeit for _ in (np.take(lut[j], img[j], axis=0) for j in xrange(planes)) : pass
   1 loops, best of 3: 434 ms per loop
   ```

The question of course is if there is no way of doing this with `np.take` without any python loop? Ideally whatever reshaping or resizing is needed should happen on the LUT, not the image, but I am open to whatever you people can come up with...

Comment: what is `bkpt` in your snippet -- no need to explain, I just wanted to alert you in case its a typo -- I guess it should be `lut`?

Comment: ... shouldn't this whole line read `lut = lut.reshape(planes, 256, 4)`, so `4` in the last dim?

Comment: @TheodrosZelleke Thanks for catching those! My `lut` is actually a **breakpoint table**, so in my code it is called `bkpt`, and that one I missed when *translating* it for the question.

Comment: really, don't know. It seems all pretty ugly. One thing, `np.take` is currently only fast if both inputs are c-contiguous (otherwise it copies them). You could translate the 2-d array to a 1-d array by hand probably, but if `img` is really large it probably doesn't matter, and if its worth the juggling around...

Comment: hi, you should give a fully working example, if too long then just create a gist on github. otherwise it is difficult for people to reproduce your problem and try to help.

Comment: ? (referring to your simpler edit): your two examples are not equivalent. The output of the second one will not be a numpy array `out` like you require. Can you timeit an equivalent example? It will probably include a call to `np.concatenate`, and I imagine the speed advantage might become much smaller.

Comment: @Juan You can give `np.take` an `out` argument, so I actually preallocate the `out` array and pass slices of it to the calls to `np.take`.

Answer (score 6):

Fist of all I have to say I really liked your question. Without rearranging `LUT` or `IMG` the following solution worked:

```
%timeit a=np.take(lut, img, axis=1)
# 1 loops, best of 3: 1.93s per loop
```

But from the result you have to query the diagonal: a[0,0], a[1,1], a[2,2]; to get what you want. I've tried to find a way to do this indexing only for the diagonal elements, but still did not manage.

Here are some ways to rearrange your `LUT` and `IMG`:
The following works if the indexes in `IMG` are from 0-255, for the 1st plane, 256-511 for the 2nd plane, and 512-767 for the 3rd plane, but that would prevent you from using `'uint8'`, which can be a big issue...:

```
lut2 = lut.reshape(-1,4)
%timeit np.take(lut2,img,axis=0)
# 1 loops, best of 3: 716 ms per loop
# or
%timeit np.take(lut2, img.flatten(), axis=0).reshape(3,4000,4000,4)
# 1 loops, best of 3: 709 ms per loop
```

in my machine your solution is still the best option, and very adequate since you just need the diagonal evaluations, i.e. plane1-plane1, plane2-plane2 and plane3-plane3:

```
%timeit for _ in (np.take(lut[j], img[j], axis=0) for j in xrange(planes)) : pass
# 1 loops, best of 3: 677 ms per loop
```

I hope this can give you some insight about a better solution. It would be nice to look for more options with `flatten()`, and similar methods as `np.apply_over_axes()` or `np.apply_along_axis()`, that seem to be promising.

I used this code below to generate the data:

```
import numpy as np
num = 4000
planes, rows, cols, n = 3, num, num, 4
lut = np.random.randint(-2**31, 2**31-1,size=(planes*256*n//4,)).view('uint8')
lut = lut.reshape(planes, 256, n)
img = np.random.randint(-2**31, 2**31-1,size=(planes*rows*cols//4,)).view('uint8')
img = img.reshape(planes, rows, cols)
```