# Using NumPy argsort and take in 2D arrays

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy, distance

The aim is to calculate the distance matrix between two sets of points (`set1` and `set2`), use `argsort()` to obtain the sorted indexes and `take()` to extract the sorted array. I know I could do a `sort()` directly, but I need the indexes for some next steps.

I am using the fancy indexing [concepts discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14491480/832621). I could not manage to use `take()` directly with the obtained matrix of indexes, but adding to each row a corresponding quantity makes it work, because `take()` flattens the source array making the second row elements with an index += len(set2), the third row index += 2*len(set2) and so forth (see below):

```
dist  = np.subtract.outer( set1[:,0], set2[:,0] )**2
dist += np.subtract.outer( set1[:,1], set2[:,1] )**2
dist += np.subtract.outer( set1[:,2], set2[:,2] )**2
a = np.argsort( dist, axis=1 )
a += np.array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
               [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
               [20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20],
               [30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30]])
s1 = np.sort(dist,axis=1)
s2 = np.take(dist,a)
np.nonzero((s1-s2)) == False
#True # meaning that it works...
```

The main question is: is there a direct way to use `take()` without summing these indexes?

Data to play with:

```
set1 = np.array([[ 250., 0.,    0.],
                 [ 250., 0.,  510.],
                 [-250., 0.,    0.],
                 [-250., 0.,    0.]])

set2 = np.array([[  61.0, 243.1, 8.3],
                 [ -43.6, 246.8, 8.4],
                 [ 102.5, 228.8, 8.4],
                 [  69.5, 240.9, 8.4],
                 [ 133.4, 212.2, 8.4],
                 [ -52.3, 245.1, 8.4],
                 [-125.8, 216.8, 8.5],
                 [-154.9, 197.1, 8.6],
                 [  61.0, 243.1, 8.7],
                 [ -26.2, 249.3, 8.7]])
```

Other related questions:

[- Euclidean distance between points in two different Numpy arrays, not within](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1871630/832621)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to use `np.take` without going to flat indices. Since dimensions are likely to change, you are better off using `np.ravel_multi_index` for that, doing something like this:

```
a = np.argsort(dist, axis=1)
a = np.ravel_multi_index((np.arange(dist.shape[0])[:, None], a), dims=dist.shape)
```

Alternatively, you can use fancy indexing without using `take`:

```
s2 = dist[np.arange(4)[:, None], a]
```

Answer (score 1):

As of may 2018 there is `np.take_along_axis`

```
s2 = np.take_along_axis(dist, a, axis=1)
```