# numpy array: replace nan values with average of columns

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, nan

I've got a numpy array filled mostly with real numbers, but there is a few `nan` values in it as well.

How can I replace the `nan`s with averages of columns where they are?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

No loops required:

```
print(a)
[[ 0.93230948         nan  0.47773439  0.76998063]
 [ 0.94460779  0.87882456  0.79615838  0.56282885]
 [ 0.94272934  0.48615268  0.06196785         nan]
 [ 0.64940216  0.74414127         nan         nan]]

#Obtain mean of columns as you need, nanmean is convenient.
col_mean = np.nanmean(a, axis=0)
print(col_mean)
[ 0.86726219  0.7030395   0.44528687  0.66640474]

#Find indices that you need to replace
inds = np.where(np.isnan(a))

#Place column means in the indices. Align the arrays using take
a[inds] = np.take(col_mean, inds[1])

print(a)
[[ 0.93230948  0.7030395   0.47773439  0.76998063]
 [ 0.94460779  0.87882456  0.79615838  0.56282885]
 [ 0.94272934  0.48615268  0.06196785  0.66640474]
 [ 0.64940216  0.74414127  0.44528687  0.66640474]]
```

Comment: Nice answer.  I didn't know nanmean existed! (+1)

Comment: any reason you use take instead of just indexing?

Comment: @Hammer They are adding nanmean to numpy in 1.8. Should be interesting. I use take instead of fancy indexing due to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14491480/using-numpy-take-for-faster-fancy-indexing) question. There is a lot of evidence that indexing is ~5x slower then take. Plus this works in older versions also.

Comment: @Jaime Can you elaborate on that some?

Comment: You can now use numpy.nanmean() instead of import scipy: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.nanmean.html

Comment: for a more up to date solution see @Donald Hobson's answer

Comment: @LetsPlayYahtzee Note to use that answer you would have to clone the `col_mean` array for every row in your original array. For this particular question the two are not comparable in terms of efficiency.

Comment: I don't think that this is true, I believe it works even if col_mean is a row

Comment: Hmm, looks like they have added additional broadcasting capabilities to `where.`

Answer (score 18):

## Using masked arrays

The standard way to do this using only numpy would be to use the [masked array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.html) module.

Scipy is a pretty heavy package which relies on external libraries, so it's worth having a numpy-only method. This borrows from @DonaldHobson's answer.

**Edit:** [`np.nanmean`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.nanmean.html) is now a numpy function. However, it doesn't handle all-nan columns...

Suppose you have an array `a`:

```
>>> a
array([[  0.,  nan,  10.,  nan],
       [  1.,   6.,  nan,  nan],
       [  2.,   7.,  12.,  nan],
       [  3.,   8.,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,   9.,  14.,  nan]])

>>> import numpy.ma as ma
>>> np.where(np.isnan(a), ma.array(a, mask=np.isnan(a)).mean(axis=0), a)    
array([[  0. ,   7.5,  10. ,   0. ],
       [  1. ,   6. ,  12. ,   0. ],
       [  2. ,   7. ,  12. ,   0. ],
       [  3. ,   8. ,  12. ,   0. ],
       [  1.5,   9. ,  14. ,   0. ]])
```

Note that the masked array's mean does not need to be the same shape as `a`, because we're taking advantage of the implicit [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) over rows.

Also note how the all-nan column is nicely handled. The mean is zero since you're taking the mean of zero elements. The method using `nanmean` doesn't handle all-nan columns:

```
>>> col_mean = np.nanmean(a, axis=0)
/home/praveen/.virtualenvs/numpy3-mkl/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/nanfunctions.py:675: RuntimeWarning: Mean of empty slice
  warnings.warn("Mean of empty slice", RuntimeWarning)
>>> inds = np.where(np.isnan(a))
>>> a[inds] = np.take(col_mean, inds[1])
>>> a
array([[  0. ,   7.5,  10. ,   nan],
       [  1. ,   6. ,  12. ,   nan],
       [  2. ,   7. ,  12. ,   nan],
       [  3. ,   8. ,  12. ,   nan],
       [  1.5,   9. ,  14. ,   nan]])
```

---

**Explanation**

Converting `a` into a masked array gives you

```
>>> ma.array(a, mask=np.isnan(a))
masked_array(data =
 [[0.0 --  10.0 --]
  [1.0 6.0 --   --]
  [2.0 7.0 12.0 --]
  [3.0 8.0 --   --]
  [--  9.0 14.0 --]],
             mask =
 [[False  True False  True]
 [False False  True  True]
 [False False False  True]
 [False False  True  True]
 [ True False False  True]],
       fill_value = 1e+20)
```

And taking the mean over columns gives you the *correct* answer, normalizing only over the non-masked values:

```
>>> ma.array(a, mask=np.isnan(a)).mean(axis=0)
masked_array(data = [1.5 7.5 12.0 --],
             mask = [False False False  True],
       fill_value = 1e+20)
```

Further, note how the mask nicely handles the column which is *all-nan*!

Finally, [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) does the job of replacement.

---

**Row-wise mean**

To replace `nan` values with row-wise mean instead of column-wise mean requires a tiny change for broadcasting to take effect nicely:

```
>>> a
array([[  0.,   1.,   2.,   3.,  nan],
       [ nan,   6.,   7.,   8.,   9.],
       [ 10.,  nan,  12.,  nan,  14.],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan]])

>>> np.where(np.isnan(a), ma.array(a, mask=np.isnan(a)).mean(axis=1), a)
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (4,5) (4,) (4,5)

>>> np.where(np.isnan(a), ma.array(a, mask=np.isnan(a)).mean(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis], a)
array([[  0. ,   1. ,   2. ,   3. ,   1.5],
       [  7.5,   6. ,   7. ,   8. ,   9. ],
       [ 10. ,  12. ,  12. ,  12. ,  14. ],
       [  0. ,   0. ,   0. ,   0. ,   0. ]])
```

Comment: IMO there's nothing wrong with having `np.nan` values as means for all-NaN column case. But it is indeed a neat case of use for masked arrays.

Comment: @VlasSokolov Well, having a mask is even better I think. i.e., making `a` into a masked array and keeping it masked even _after_ applying the mean. Then you don't need to worry about performing operations on it, which might cause the `nan`s to "spread" to the non-`nan` values.

Answer (score 6):

If **partial** is your original data, and **replace** is an array of the same shape containing averaged values then this code will use the value from partial if one exists.

```
Complete= np.where(np.isnan(partial),replace,partial)
```

Comment: This is a much, much cleaner solution than any of the others presented.

Comment: Except that it requires more memory, to hold the repeated mean values.

Answer (score 4):

**Alternative**: Replacing NaNs with interpolation of columns.

```
def interpolate_nans(X):
    """Overwrite NaNs with column value interpolations."""
    for j in range(X.shape[1]):
        mask_j = np.isnan(X[:,j])
        X[mask_j,j] = np.interp(np.flatnonzero(mask_j), np.flatnonzero(~mask_j), X[~mask_j,j])
    return X
```

Example use:

```
X_incomplete = np.array([[10,     20,     30    ],
                         [np.nan, 30,     np.nan],
                         [np.nan, np.nan, 50    ],
                         [40,     50,     np.nan    ]])

X_complete = interpolate_nans(X_incomplete)

print X_complete
[[10,     20,     30    ],
 [20,     30,     40    ],
 [30,     40,     50    ],
 [40,     50,     50    ]]
```

I use this bit of code for time series data in particular, where columns are attributes and rows are time-ordered samples.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't very clean but I can't think of a way to do it other than iterating

```
#example
a = np.arange(16, dtype = float).reshape(4,4)
a[2,2] = np.nan
a[3,3] = np.nan

indices = np.where(np.isnan(a)) #returns an array of rows and column indices
for row, col in zip(*indices):
    a[row,col] = np.mean(a[~np.isnan(a[:,col]), col])
```

Answer (score 2):

To extend Donald's Answer I provide a minimal example. Let's say `a` is an ndarray and we want to replace its zero values with the mean of the column.

```
In [231]: a
Out[231]: 
array([[0, 3, 6],
       [2, 0, 0]])


In [232]: col_mean = np.nanmean(a, axis=0)
Out[232]: array([ 1. ,  1.5,  3. ])

In [228]: np.where(np.equal(a, 0), col_mean, a)
Out[228]: 
array([[ 1. ,  3. ,  6. ],
       [ 2. ,  1.5,  3. ]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using simple functions with loops:

```
a=[[0.93230948, np.nan, 0.47773439, 0.76998063],
  [0.94460779, 0.87882456, 0.79615838, 0.56282885],
  [0.94272934, 0.48615268, 0.06196785, np.nan],
  [0.64940216, 0.74414127, np.nan, np.nan],
  [0.64940216, 0.74414127, np.nan, np.nan]]

print("------- original array -----")
for aa in a:
    print(aa)

# GET COLUMN MEANS: 
ta = np.array(a).T.tolist()                         # transpose the array; 
col_means = list(map(lambda x: np.nanmean(x), ta))  # get means; 
print("column means:", col_means)

# REPLACE NAN ENTRIES WITH COLUMN MEANS: 
nrows = len(a); ncols = len(a[0]) # get number of rows & columns; 
for r in range(nrows):
    for c in range(ncols):
        if np.isnan(a[r][c]):
            a[r][c] = col_means[c]

print("------- means added -----")
for aa in a:
    print(aa)
```

Output:

```
------- original array -----
[0.93230948, nan, 0.47773439, 0.76998063]
[0.94460779, 0.87882456, 0.79615838, 0.56282885]
[0.94272934, 0.48615268, 0.06196785, nan]
[0.64940216, 0.74414127, nan, nan]
[0.64940216, 0.74414127, nan, nan]

column means: [0.82369018599999999, 0.71331494500000003, 0.44528687333333333, 0.66640474000000005]

------- means added -----
[0.93230948, 0.71331494500000003, 0.47773439, 0.76998063]
[0.94460779, 0.87882456, 0.79615838, 0.56282885]
[0.94272934, 0.48615268, 0.06196785, 0.66640474000000005]
[0.64940216, 0.74414127, 0.44528687333333333, 0.66640474000000005]
[0.64940216, 0.74414127, 0.44528687333333333, 0.66640474000000005]
```

The for loops can also be written with list comprehension:

```
new_a = [[col_means[c] if np.isnan(a[r][c]) else a[r][c] 
            for c in range(ncols) ]
        for r in range(nrows) ]
```

Answer (score -3):

you might want to try this built-in function:

```
x = np.array([np.inf, -np.inf, np.nan, -128, 128])
np.nan_to_num(x)
array([  1.79769313e+308,  -1.79769313e+308,   0.00000000e+000,
-1.28000000e+002,   1.28000000e+002])
```