# Working with missing data, using dataframe values to fill nan, interpolate

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

My sample dataframe consists of:

```
dictx = {'col':[20,'nan',22,'nan','nan','nan',30,'nan',28,'nan',25]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dictx).astype(float)
df = df.reset_index()
```

**PART 1**
I need to fill those missing data with either the mean of the extremities, e.g.

```
df1 = df.iloc[:3,[1]]
   col
0  20.0
1   NaN
2  22.0
```

The value for the index `1`should be 21.
This problem will reappear on other situations which also need the same treatment

**PART 2**
Or when the NaN's are more than one, I need to plot the data from a line chart as follow:

```
df2 = df.iloc[2:7,[1]]
   col
2  22.0
3   NaN
4   NaN
5   NaN
6  30.0

x = df.iat[6,1]
x0 = df.iat[2,1]
y = df.iat[6,0]
y0 = df.iat[2,0]

slope = (x - x0)/(y-y0)
value = slope*(x - x0) + y0
```

So the value would vary for each index

**My objectives are:**
The real dataframe is constantly changing and has 1440 rows so this problem repeats over and over.
I need more help in part 1, because I can apply a similar approach for part 2 using the logic from the first.

Comment: Can you try df.interpolate()?  Does that yield the results expecting?

Comment: possible duplicate with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18689823/pandas-dataframe-replace-nan-values-with-average-of-columns

Comment: Well... That was disappointing I was expecting much more
difficulty, that's what I need! @ScottBoston

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to do linear interpolation, use [`interpolate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html#pandas-dataframe-interpolate):

Let's try:

```
df.interpolate()
```

Output:

```
    index   col
0       0  20.0
1       1  21.0
2       2  22.0
3       3  24.0
4       4  26.0
5       5  28.0
6       6  30.0
7       7  29.0
8       8  28.0
9       9  26.5
10     10  25.0
```