# Pandas Get Two Previous and Two Next non-NaN Values in Column

Tags: pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame with a column containing some missing data. I want to try an imputation strategy where for a `NaN` point, I impute the point with a value drawn from a distribution centered at a weighted average of the previous two and next two non-`NaN` data points. I am not sure how in Pandas to get those values, ideally as an `np.ndarray`.

For example if I had this DataFrame:

```
0 12
1 33
2 Nan
3 22
4 Nan
5 7
```

I would like a function called on row 2 to return [12, 33, 22, 7]. If it were called on row 4 to return [33, 22, 7, None].

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51559529/pandas-dynamically-replace-nan-values-with-the-average-of-previous-and-next-non) deals with a similar problem, but not exactly what I am looking for.