# Pandas: Replace NaN with Average by Multi Level Index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes `df_country_cluster` and `df_countries`, with the following structure (in order):

```
            cluster_id
country_id
1                    4
2                    4
...                  ...

                     col1   col2   col3   col4
country_id  year_id
1           2015     0.1    0.2    0.3    0.1
1           2016     0.4    NaN    0.1    0.8
1           2017     0.7    0.2    0.6    NaN
1           2018     0.9    0.4    0.7    0.2  
2           2015     0.5    0.6    NaN    0.3 
2           2016     0.3    0.7    0.2    0.5 
2           2017     0.2    0.9    0.3    0.5 
2           2018     0.1    0.2    0.1    0.9 
...         ...      ...    ...    ...    ...
```

My goal is to fill the NaN values with the average non-NaN values of each cluster and year. This means that, for example, the NaN in `country_id` 1, `year_id` 2016, `col2` should be filled with the average of the valid values of `col2` for 2016 and all the countries with `cluster_id` 4 (in this case).

In the above example, we would get the averages of `cluster_id` 4 in this way:

```
                     col1   col2   col3   col4
cluster_id  year_id
4           2015     0.3    0.4    *0.3   0.2
4           2016     0.4    *0.7   0.2    0.6
4           2017     0.4    0.6    0.4    *0.5
4           2018     0.5    0.3    0.4    0.6
```

Therefore, the NaN each column would be filled by the values with a *.

I have tried to create a new `DataFrame` with `groupby().mean()`, and then use `.fillna`, but without success. Other SO questions [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18689823/pandas-dataframe-replace-nan-values-with-average-of-columns) only discuss the single-index problem.

Here is my approach:

```
    cols = ['col1','col2','col3','col4']
    original_index = df_countries.index

    df_countries = df_countries.join(df_country_cluster,on='country_id')
    df_countries = df_countries.reset_index().set_index(['cluster_id','year_id'])
    avg_cluster = df_countries.groupby(['cluster_id','year_id']).mean()
    avg_cluster = avg_cluster[cols]

    for col in cols:
        df_countries[col].fillna(avg_cluster[col],inplace=True)

    df_countries.reset_index().set_index(original_index)
```

Comment: What is expected output? What are numbers instead NaNs ?

Comment: The expected output is to have the df_countries dataframe with the NaN filled by the  average non-NaN values of each cluster and year.

Comment: Hi, it is not clear to me how you want to take the average. In your example, since there is only one `country_id=1` for `year_id=2016` it is not possible to take an average. I get that this is only an example. But I think perhaps you should take an example where it is possible to find the average. Or am I not understanding something?

Comment: @nunoapedro - For me unclear too, so ask what are averages numbers from sample data? What is number for repalce first NaN, for second and similar? It seems your data are not [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hey @mortysporty and jezrael, it wasn't clear in the questions, but I've updated the tables. The data is complete in that each country_id has a cluster_id between 1 and 4, and there are 50 countries,  each with data from 2015 to 2018. I have only included an example.

Comment: When I run `df_countries.groupby(['cluster_id','year_id']).mean()` I get the average of each cluster / year

Comment: Hi again. I dont see how you adding that last row changes anything with regards to my earlier comment. Based on the provided data it is still not possible to create an average for `cluster_id=4` and `year_id=2016` for `co2l`. Anyway, I created some dummy data based on my understanding of what you want… and running your code it seems to me you get the desired output. Im struggeling to understand your problem...

Comment: I think perhaps you should provide an example of your desired output....

Comment: @mortysporty, the output is the `df_countries` dataframe with the NaN values filled. I've added more info that should help explain what I need. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.

```
df_countries = df_countries.reset_index().set_index(original_index)
```

Forgot to keep the answer with the correct index... With this change, it works.
However, if anyone has a more pythonic way to do it, please add your answer!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand you right. But your approach looks good. So we start with

```
df = df_countries.join(df_country_cluster, on='country_id')
df = df.reset_index().set_index(['cluster_id','year_id'])
```

You say that the fill value is the mean per group:

```
s = df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']].mean(axis=1)
```

We can put things togehter if we transpose the DataFrame

```
df = df.T.fillna(value=s).T
```

Finally we drop what we don't need

```
df = df.reset_index().drop(columns='cluster_id').set_index('country_id', 'year_id')
```

Comment: The fill value would have to be the mean per cluster and year, something along the lines of what `avg_cluster` prints. However, I will try transposing the DataFrame.

Comment: `s` is the mean per cluster and year, have a look at the `axis=1` argument.

Comment: thank you, that's right, it does calculate the mean by cluster and year. However, when I print it, it averages col1, col2, col3 and col4 - I would need the average of each column (but by cluster, year), and apply that to the country, year NaN values