# pandas DataFrame: replace nan values with median of corresponding column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have some NaN values in my pd dataframe and I wish to replace them with the median value of the column. I am aware that this is very similar to: 
[pandas DataFrame: replace nan values with average of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18689823/pandas-dataframe-replace-nan-values-with-average-of-columns/42464349)

However when I try the equivalent:

```
df = df.fillna(df.median())
```

I get the following error:

```
Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py:6287: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  self._update_inplace(new_data)
Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:4244: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  **kwargs
```

Any advice is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: `A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame`: is your `df` a part of some bigger dataframe?

Comment: do `df = df.copy()` above that line. You can read extensively about it in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas

Comment: Yes, I extracted it from a larger one. How can I extract it without getting this error?
I used this initially: 
df = data.iloc[:, 0:-1]

Comment: agreed with @ALollz, do a copy of your dataframe. Additional resource: https://www.dataquest.io/blog/settingwithcopywarning/

Comment: @ALollz that did not work unfortunately.

Comment: If you want to update `data`, do `data.iloc[:,0:-1] = df.fillna(df.median)`. If not, you should include an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Perfect, that worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try `df.fillna(df.median(axis=1, skipna=True))`