# Series.replace cannot use dict-like to_replace and non-None value

Tags: pandas, numpy, series

I have a DataFrame with the fields as shown.
[Dataframe fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzVPm.png)

I am trying to fill the null values with the median of the column **Loan_Amount_Term** with the below code: (The column has 14 null values)

`hd['Loan_Amount_Term'] = hd['Loan_Amount_Term'].replace(np.isnan(hd['Loan_Amount_Term']),hd['Loan_Amount_Term'].median())`

But I am getting the following error:
***Series.replace cannot use dict-like to_replace and non-None value***

I want to know why I cannot impute the null values with median in this way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: change `.mean` to `.median` and use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33178896)

Comment: @jezrael this is replacing the entire **Loan_amount_term** column to **None**.

Comment: then use `df.Loan_amount_term = df.Loan_amount_term.replace('None', np.nan)` before this solution

Comment: It works fine if I remove **inplace = True** argument. Thanks @jezrael
But I want to know why **replace** is not a good fit here.