# why do i get RecursionError after changing NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, data-analysis

I changed the Nan values by iterating through the columns and after that i get RecursionError when i try to view the dataframe

```
for i in df.columns:
   df[i].fillna(df[i].mean, inplace=True)

df
```

Edit:
Reproducible code

```
# import pandas and load cancer data
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("cancer_data_means.csv")

# check which columns have missing values with info()
df.info()

# use means to fill in missing values
for i in df.columns:
  df[i].fillna(df[i].mean, inplace=True)

# confirm your correction with info()
df.info()
df
```

Comment: Did you take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18689823/pandas-dataframe-replace-nan-values-with-average-of-columns ?

Comment: Please add a few test data to your code so that people may run it to reproduce the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: @gudumoni yeah but i want to know why i get this error.

Comment: @bjhend Thank you,Done.

Comment: @DODE That's way better, but we are still missing the test data, because we do not have the CSV file you load. Instead of the `pd.read_csv` command just assign some data directly to `df` that will trigger the error. And besides, it may also help to insert the exact error message into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Generally changing the object that you are iterating over directly like this can cause weird behavior. You should be able to do it in a single step using

```
df.fillna({col: df[col].mean for col in df.columns}, axis=1)
```

Comment: yes i know i can use another ways i just want to why it causes this error thank you.