# Conditional imputation with average of non-missing columns with pandas toolbox

Tags: pandas, spss

This question focus on pandas own functions. There are still solutions ([pandas DataFrame: replace nan values with average of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18689823/4865723)) but with own written functions.

In SPSS there is function `MEAN.n` which gives you the mean value of list of numbers **only** when `n` elements of that list are valid (`not pandas.NA`). With that function you are able to imputat missing values only if a minimum number of items are valid.

Are there pandas function to do this with?

**Example**

Values `[1, 2, 3, 4, NA]`.
Mean of the valid values is `2.5`.
The resulting list should be `[1, 2, 3, 4, 2.5]`.

Assume the rule that in a 5 item list 3 should have valid values for imputation. Otherwise the result is NA.

Values `[1, 2, NA, NA, NA]`.
Mean of the valid values is `1.5` but it does not matter.
The resulting list should not be changed `[1, 2, NA, NA, NA]` because imputation is not allowed.

Comment: How is the input dataframe?

Comment: Provide the input and output dataframes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to work with `pandas`, you can define a custom wrapper (using only pandas functions) to `fillna` with the `mean` only if a minimum number of items are not NA:

```
from pandas import NA
s1 = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4, NA])
s2 = pd.Series([1, 2, NA, NA, NA])

def fillna_mean(s, N=4):
    return s if s.notna().sum() < N else s.fillna(s.mean())

fillna_mean(s1)
# 0    1.0
# 1    2.0
# 2    3.0
# 3    4.0
# 4    2.5
# dtype: float64

fillna_mean(s2)
# 0       1
# 1       2
# 2    <NA>
# 3    <NA>
# 4    <NA>
# dtype: object

fillna_mean(s2, N=2)
# 0    1.0
# 1    2.0
# 2    1.5
# 3    1.5
# 4    1.5
# dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets try list comprehension, though it will be messy

Option1

You can use pd.Series and numpy

```
  s= [x if np.isnan(lst).sum()>=3 else pd.Series(lst).mean(skipna=True) if x is np.nan else x for x in lst]
```

Option2 use numpy all through

```
 s=[x if np.isnan(lst).sum()>=3 else np.mean([x for x in lst if str(x) != 'nan']) if x is np.nan else x for x in lst]
```

**Case1**

```
lst=[1, 2, 3, 4, np.nan]
```

outcome

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 2.5]
```

**Case2**

```
lst=[1, 2, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]
```

outcome

```
[1, 2, nan, nan, nan]
```

if you wanted it as a pd. Series, simply

```
pd.Series(s, name='lst')
```

**How it works**

```
s=[x if np.isnan(lst).sum()>=3 \ #give me element x if the sum of nans in the list is greater than or equal to 3
   
   else pd.Series(lst).mean(skipna=True) if x is np.nan else x \# Otherwise replace the Nan in list with the mean of non NaN elements in the list
   
   for x in lst\#For every element in lst
  ]
```