# Nan values not getting replaced

Tags: python, pandas

The values are getting replaced but the moment i print the `data` it still shows the nan values

```
for col in data.columns:
    for each in range(len(data[col])):
        if math.isnan(data[col][each]) == True:
            data.replace(data[col][each], statistics.mean(data[col]))
 data
```

dataset: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AVTVmUVs9lSe7I9EXoPs0gNaSIo9KM2PrXxwVWeqtME/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like what you are trying to do is to replace NaN values by the mean of each column, which has been treated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18689823/pandas-dataframe-replace-nan-values-with-average-of-columns)

Regarding your problem, the function `replace(a,b)` replaces all the values in your dataframe that are equal to `a` by `b`.

Moreover, the function `statistics.mean` will return `NaN` if there is a Nan number in your list, so you should use `numpy.nanmean()` instead.

Comment: Still not working after adding inplace =True

Comment: Sorry, I edited my comment

Comment: Thanks it worked