# How to replace NULL values with Mean value of a category in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, missing-data

I have a dataset with null values in the column 'revenues_from_appointment'

**Dataset**

| appointment_date | patient_id | practitioner_id | appointment_duration_min | revenues_from_appointment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-06-28 | 42734 | 748 | 30 | 90.0 |
| 2021-06-29 | 42737 | 747 | 60 | 150.0 |
| 2021-07-01 | 42737 | 747 | 60 | **NaN** |
| 2021-07-03 | 42736 | 748 | 30 | 60.0 |
| 2021-07-03 | 42735 | 747 | 15 | 42.62 |
| 2021-07-04 | 42734 | 748 | 30 | **NaN** |
| 2021-07-05 | 42734 | 748 | 30 | 100.0 |
| 2021-07-10 | 42738 | 747 | 15 | 50.72 |
| 2021-08-12 | 42739 | 748 | 30 | 73.43 |

I wish to replace NULL values by the mean value of rows where "*patient_id, practitioner_id, appointment_duration_min*" is the same.

I did it using pandas dataframe,

```
df['revenues_from_appointment'].fillna(df.groupby(['patient_id','practitioner_id','appointment_duration_min'])['revenues_from_appointment'].transform('mean'), inplace = True)
```

**How can we obtain the same result by using SQL?**

#### Final Output

| appointment_date | patient_id | practitioner_id | appointment_duration_min | revenues_from_appointment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-06-28 | 42734 | 748 | 30 | 90.0 |
| 2021-06-29 | 42737 | 747 | 60 | 150.0 |
| 2021-07-01 | 42737 | 747 | 60 | **150.0** |
| 2021-07-03 | 42736 | 748 | 30 | 60.0 |
| 2021-07-03 | 42735 | 747 | 15 | 42.62 |
| 2021-07-04 | 42734 | 748 | 30 | **95.0** |
| 2021-07-05 | 42734 | 748 | 30 | 100.0 |
| 2021-07-10 | 42738 | 747 | 15 | 50.72 |
| 2021-08-12 | 42739 | 748 | 30 | 73.43 |

Comment: mysql and sql server are two different database products with different sql syntax. Which one do you use?

Comment: I am trying on ms-sql

Comment: I had a similar issue, used python to replace the NULL values as shown in this link.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18689823/pandas-dataframe-replace-nan-values-with-average-of-columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `AVG` window function, that will partition on the three column of interest and replace null values using the `COALESCE` function:

```
SELECT appointment_date,
       patient_id,
       practitioner_id,
       appointment_duration_min,
       COALESCE(revenues_from_appointment, 
                AVG(revenues_from_appointment) OVER(PARTITION BY patient_id, 
                                                                 practitioner_id, 
                                                                 appointment_duration_min))
FROM tab
```

Try it [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=71f59ee82e2ed2ef98f9d5a6ba109afc).