# RandomForestClassifier : Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32')

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

[Code I have written](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fydOm.png)

[Example of starting Random Forest Classifier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8z9X.png)

[I can not figure out why I am getting this error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m350U.png)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your data contain empty values, which will be represented as `NaN` (Not a Number) by pandas. So you need to preprocess your data.

1. In case your data have infinity values, you can replace them first by using `data = data.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)`
2. Then you need to either drop the rows which contain `NaN` values using `data = data.dropna()`, or fill NaN values with 0, mean or median value of your data with `data = data.fillna()`

For further information, you can check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18689823/pandas-dataframe-replace-nan-values-with-average-of-columns).