# Mean imputation return None and Nan in Dataframe

Tags: pandas, mean, missing-data, fillna

I want to fill in the missing values of two columns with the mean method. I type of the two columns is float64.

```
df['col1'].dtypes
dtype('float64')
df['col2'].dtypes
dtype('float64')
```

I used two methods to fill the columns. 1st I fill the nan values with '0'.

```
df.replace(np.nan,0, inplace=True )
```

Then I used fillna.mean() method to fill the columns

```
 df['col1']=df['col1'].fillna(df['col1'].mean(), inplace=True)
```

This is return something like that

```
Col1
Nan
Nan
Nan
```

I tried second method without first filling the nan values with zero and directly applied mean imputation method which return "None".

I did not understand what was wrong with my implementation. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) of your dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution (you need to use `skipna=True` when calculating the mean):

```
df['col1'].fillna(df['col1'].mean(skipna=True), inplace=True)
```

Comment: I did that. I tried it without filling the "Nan" value with zero. However, it did not change the output. It still 'None'

Comment: It is hard to diagnose the problem without a piece of your data, @Encipher. For instance, the following works fine: `df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': [1, np.nan, 3],
    'col2': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    'col3': [1, 2, 3]})

df['col1'].fillna(df['col1'].mean(skipna=True), inplace=True)`

Comment: Another thing I noticed when I first found out the datatype without replacement the datatype was "dtype('float64')". After imputation and getting None vale the datatype is dtype('O')

Comment: I don't know what's the problem. I made a trick. I separated only that column from the dataframe and use mean imputation and that worked well. I don't know what should be its possible explanation. "data = df.col1", data.fillna(data.mean(), inplace = True)

Comment: You might also try: `df['col1'].replace(np.nan, df['col1'].mean())`.

Comment: Thank you. Its work. Can you please explain what's the difference between this command with previous commands?

Comment: Without seeing the data, it is hard to find an explanation, @Encipher.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the question:
"Then I used fillna.mean() method to fill the columns"

> df['col1']=df['col1'].fillna(df['col1'].mean(), inplace=True)

**Remove the inplace argument since you assign the column. This is the first mistake.**

After clearing this typo, this works perfectly despite years past: [pandas DataFrame: replace nan values with average of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18689823/12846804)

> df.fillna(df.mean())

Verified with a fresh random example:

```
   col1  col2
0   1.0   NaN
1   0.1   1.0
2   NaN   3.2
3   4.0   NaN
4   8.0   0.0
```

```
df.fillna(df.mean())
    col1  col2
0  1.000   1.4
1  0.100   1.0
2  3.275   3.2
3  4.000   1.4
4  8.000   0.0
```

**There is no need to replace NaN with 0 in the first place** (nor to skipna when calculating the means, as another answer suggested).