# To fit polynomial function to fill the NaN value in my data frame

Tags: python, data-analysis

[image]Good evening everyone, I have a data frame with 226 columns and 1110 instances. Some values in some rows have nan values so I'm goin to fill these values by condition. First, the minimum value for start filling should be the latest value before nan value in each row. Second, the maximum value should be the latest column and if the last value before first nan is equal to maximum the nan values will fill with maximum.
There is final code that shows the data frame with nan values. Because the main data set is to big I won't be able to upload it and I just share a photo of my out put in python.

```
# hi_1_df = health indecatore 1 data frame
hi_1_df = pd.DataFrame(pivoted_df.values, columns=[f'v{i+1}' for i in range(pivoted_df.shape[1])], index=pivoted_df.index)

capacity_df= cs2_df.groupby('Cycle_ID')['Max_Capacity'].max()

hi_1_df['Max_voltage']=cs2_df['Voltage(V)'].max()

# Merge max_capacity_df into app_df based on 'Cycle_ID'
hi_1_df = hi_1_df.merge(capacity_df, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='left')

hi_1_df
```

I expect the value of nan to be filled with correct values using the appropriate polynomial function where NaN is replaced with the appropriate values that are incremented in order.

Comment: Can you please post an example of sample input and what the expected output would look like?

Comment: My input of function should be a row which is included nan values and the output should be a row with continues values to Max_voltage

Comment: That's usually what you use fillna for, have a look at [pandas DataFrame: replace nan values with average of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18689823/pandas-dataframe-replace-nan-values-with-average-of-columns)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the .ffill() function to forward fill values from left to right. [Reference](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html)

```
df.ffill(axis = 1)
```