# Python Data Frame: def function to change NaN values in each column to the mean of each column

Tags: python, function

I have the following dataset (df):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wg4bB.png)

I would like to write a def Python if/else function that would change every NaN value in each column to the mean of values in their respective column.

I found a simple solution without def function:

```
df2 = df.apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()), axis = 0)
```

But I would also know how I would achieve the same result with a def function?
I tried:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def my_func(x):
if x is None:
return x.mean()
else:
return x

df2 = df.apply(lambda x : my_func(x), axis=1)
```

But it is not working.
Thank you for tips!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas DataFrame: replace nan values with average of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18689823/pandas-dataframe-replace-nan-values-with-average-of-columns)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the solution provided in the comment, you can do something like this:

```
def fill_nan_with_mean(df):
    means = df.mean()
    df.fillna(means, inplace=True)
```

if you want to specify the column:

```
def fill_nan_with_mean(df, column_name):

    mean_value = df[column_name].mean()
    df[column_name].fillna(mean_value, inplace=True)
```

Comment: If the answer is what you were looking for, please consider to mark it as the correct answer (and upvote if you want). Thanks